SFINAE for checking the validity of a complex expression involving copy assignment
Consider the following classes and take specific note of Concrete<T>::copy_assign:
struct TypeErased
{
    TypeErased() = default;
    TypeErased& operator=(TypeErased const& other) {
        copy_assign(other);
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void copy_assign(TypeErased const& other) = 0;
    virtual ~TypeErased(){}
};

template <typename T>
class Concrete : public TypeErased
{
public:

    template <typename... Args>
    Concrete(Args&&... args) : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T const& get_value() const  {
        return value;
    }

    void copy_assign(TypeErased const& other) override final
    {
        copy_assign_impl(other);
    }

private:

    template <typename U=T>
    void copy_assign_impl(TypeErased const& other) {
        if constexpr (std::is_copy_assignable_v<U>) {
            value = static_cast<Concrete<U> const&>(other).get_value();
        } else {
            throw std::logic_error("Nope!");
        }
    }

    T value;
};

I need the constexpr-if to be able to instantiate Concrete<T> instances, even if T is not copy-assignable. If one attempts to copy-assign a Concrete<T> with not copy-assignable T, I want to throw a runtime error.
struct NoCopy {
    NoCopy() = default;
    NoCopy(NoCopy const&) = delete;
    NoCopy& operator=(NoCopy const&) = delete;
};



int main()
{
    // These work:
    Concrete<double> x1; // trivial
    Concrete<std::vector<double>> x2;
    Concrete<NoCopy> x3;
    Concrete<std::unique_ptr<double>> x4;
    Concrete<std::optional<NoCopy>> x5;
}

Now my problem is, that the if-constexpr condition is not exhaustive. I keep on stumbling over situations, where the condition std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> evaluates to true, but the expression value = static_cast<Concrete<T> const&>(other).get_value(); is invalid. For instance, all of the following instantiations are compiler errors:
Concrete<boost::optional<NoCopy>> x6;
Concrete<std::vector<NoCopy>> x7;  
Concrete<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<double>>> x8;
Concrete<boost::variant<std::string&, boost::optional<std::string>&>> // I know this is weird, but the types used in Concrete come from external libraries and are not in my hand

https://godbolt.org/z/6dxh1a7rK
Is there a type trait or some SFINAE magic that I could use, to reliably test the validity of the expression value = static_cast<Concrete<T> const&>(other).get_value(); using C++17 features only?
Note: I asked a similar question, when I thought that I had a problem just with boost::optional: Unexpected behavior of std::is_copy_assignable and boost::optional

If the thing being checked is not SFINAE-friendly, you can't do anything. You need some heuristics to guess copyability.

if constexpr only works in function templates.  copy_assign is not a function template.

@NathanOliver I edited my question accordingly. Now copy_assign redirects to a function template with if constexpr. The issue persists.

@HolyBlackCat, I was hoping of finding a workaround that checks the validity of an expression, rather than properties of the SFINAE-unfriendly types used in that expression.


I keep on stumbling over situations, where the condition std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> evaluates to true, but the expression value = static_cast<Concrete<T> const&>(other).get_value(); is invalid. For instance, all of the following instantiations are compiler errors:
Concrete<boost::optional<NoCopy>> x6;
Concrete<std::vector<NoCopy>> x7;  
Concrete<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<double>>> x8;


The root cause here is "SFINAE special members or support incomplete types: Pick at most one" (2020-02-05).
First, consider that you will never ever ever be able to handle an evil type like this:
template<class T>
struct Evil {
    Evil& operator=(const Evil&) {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0);
    }
};

static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Evil<int>>);

This type claims to be copy-assignable, but as soon as you try to instantiate the definition of its operator=, it hard-errors. (This error is "not in an immediate context" — it's not merely a substitution failure.)
So then your question is simply "Why does vector<NoCopy> behave like Evil<int>?" and the answer is simply "SFINAE special members or support incomplete types: Pick at most one". vector has to decide up front whether it's going to look and see whether NoCopy is copyable (in which case NoCopy must be a complete type, and then you can't have struct Node { vector<Node> children; } anymore), or whether it's going to optimistically assume it's copyable (which it does; and then you have exactly the Evil case).

Ah great answer, though not what I hoped for. So in essence, there is no way to have a copy-assignable type erased type, that delegates the copy assignment at runtime?

There certainly is; std::any and std::function are both such type-erased types. What you can't do is magically handle a type that lies to you about whether it supports assignment; and you just have to make your peace with the fact that vector<MoveOnly> is such a type.

Or, to put it another way, C++ gives you a way to "try compiling an expression and backtrack if it turns out ill-formed," i.e. SFINAE, which is the same mechanism used in C++20 requires-expressions; but this existing mechanism is very limited and can backtrack only from the immediate context. C++ provides no mechanism powerful enough to backtrack from an error that happens arbitrarily deep in an instantiation.
